# Replace with multiple elements in a column based on condition

Tags: r, search, replace

I am having some problems replacing a value in a column of a dataframe.

**I have two dataframes that looks like this:**

a results table:

`r <- data.frame(d = c("100", "100,111", "100,111,123"), r = c("3", "3,6,7", "42,57"))`

a mapping table:

`m <- data.frame(id = c("3", "6", "7", "42", "57", "100", "111", "123"), name= c("tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "tc4", "tc5", "tc6", "tc7", "tc8"))`

Now  I want the strings in `m$name`to replace the numbers in `r$d` and `r$r` based on a match/partial match in `m$id`, the hard part being for me, that multiple numbers can appear.

Example: The tuple "100,111" "3,6,7" should be "tc6,tc7" "tc1,tc2,tc3" in the end.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one liner using base R,

```
r[] <- lapply(r, function(i) sapply(strsplit(as.character(i), ','), 
                                function(j)paste(m$name[match(j, m$id)], collapse = ',')))
```

which gives,

> ```
>             d           r
> 1         tc6         tc1
> 2     tc6,tc7 tc1,tc2,tc3
> 3 tc6,tc7,tc8     tc4,tc5
> ```

Answer (score 4):

`gsubfn` will replace each match to the pattern in its first argument replacing that match with the value corresponding to that name in the list given in the second argument.  We `lapply` that to each column of `r`.

```
library(gsubfn)

L <- with(m, as.list(setNames(as.character(name), id)))
replace(r, TRUE, lapply(r, function(x) gsubfn("\\d+", L, as.character(x)))
```

giving:

```
            d           r
1         tc6         tc1
2     tc6,tc7 tc1,tc2,tc3
3 tc6,tc7,tc8     tc4,tc5
```

### Note

If the columns of `r` and `m` were character rather than factor then we could simplify that a bit.

```
m[] <- lapply(m, as.character)
r[] <- lapply(r, as.character)

L <- with(m, as.list(setNames(name, id)))
r[] <- lapply(r, gsubfn, pattern = "\\d+", replacement = L)
```

or use this for the last line if you want to preserve the input `r`

```
replace(r, TRUE, lapply(r, gsubfn, pattern = "\\d+", replacement = L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` way would be to get the column in long format, separate the rows based on comma, `group_by`  every row and column and create a comma-separated string. Finally, we get the data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

r %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, values_to = 'id') %>%
  separate_rows(id, sep = ",", convert = TRUE)  %>%
  left_join(m %>% 
             type.convert(as.is = TRUE), by = 'id')  %>%
  group_by(row, name.x)  %>%
  summarise(name = toString(name.y)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name.x, values_from = name) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  d             r            
#  <chr>         <chr>        
#1 tc6           tc1          
#2 tc6, tc7      tc1, tc2, tc3
#3 tc6, tc7, tc8 tc4, tc5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way of doing this, using the `apply` functions.  We can use `lapply` on the `d` and `r` columns (only code for `d` shown), and then iterate over the data frame of terms with replacements.  Then, we call `sub` for each term/replacement found.

```
r$d <- lapply(r$d, function(x) {
    apply(m, 1, function(y) {
        x <<- gsub(paste0("\\b", y[1], "\\b"), y[2], x)
    })
    return(x)
})
r

               d     r
1         tc6     3
2     tc6,tc7 3,6,7
3 tc6,tc7,tc8 42,57
```

**Data:**

```
r <- data.frame(d = c("100", "100,111", "100,111,123"), r = c("3", "3,6,7", "42,57"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
m <- data.frame(id = c("3", "6", "7", "42", "57", "100", "111", "123"), name= c("tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "tc4", "tc5", "tc6", "tc7", "tc8"))
```

Note that using the `<<-` parent scope assignment operator is often evil, but in this case, I am using it to refer to the scope defined in the outer call to `lapply`, so perhaps it is more acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested solution using base R:

```
r <- data.frame(d = c("100", "100,111", "100,111,123"), r = c("3", "3,6,7", "42,57"))
m <- data.frame(id = c("3", "6", "7", "42", "57", "100", "111", "123"), name= c("tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "tc4", "tc5", "tc6", "tc7", "tc8"))
```

Convert factors to character:

```
m <- apply(m, 2, as.character)
r <- apply(r, 2, as.character)
```

Loop through each cell and replace elements of tuples using `m`:

```
result <- r
for (i in seq_along(r[, 1])) {
  for (j in seq_along(r[1, ])) {
    result[i, j] <- paste0(sapply(strsplit(r[i, j], ","), function(x) m[m[, 1] %in% x, 2]), collapse=", ")
  }
}
```

`result` is now:

> ```
>      d               r              
> [1,] "tc6"           "tc1"          
> [2,] "tc6, tc7"      "tc1, tc2, tc3"
> [3,] "tc6, tc7, tc8" "tc4, tc5"
> ```